# EVA plugin: How to check the add value in " temp = (volatile unsigned short*) add " through the temp variable

Tags: c, frama-c

I am trying to check the add value in " temp = (volatile unsigned short*) add " through the temp variable in the following example:

```
main() {
    unsigned short add = 0x01;
    unsigned short val = 0x00;
    unsigned short *temp;
    temp = (volatile unsigned short*) add;
    *temp = val;
    //@ assert &temp == (unsigned short) 0x01;
}
```

But I got this error at line "//@ assert &temp == (unsigned short) 0x01;"

```
[kernel] user error: incompatible types unsigned short and unsigned short **
[kernel] user error: stopping on file "test_func_call.c" that has errors. Add '-kernel-msg-key pp'for preprocessing command.
```

I know it may be all about C, but I use Frama-C's tag as well. Hope that I can receive the answer on checking the add value by Frama-C.

Comment: The address 0x01 is most likely not valid.  What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Yes, you're right. 0x01 is just a dummy value I use in this example. I'm trying to verify for an embedded program. So the value will be different.

Comment: Any reason you'd expect the address of `temp` to be `0x01`?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to get the add value through the temp variable. Take &temp is one of my attempts. I do not have clear reason for that. It's just a trial. As the error message, I know that &temp is not the right way to get the value of add variable.

Comment: From your comment, I infer you wanted `//@assert add == 0x01;`, but probably that assertion got status Invalid and then you tried something else? If so, the way to deal with hardware-mapped registers in Frama-C is to use option `-absolute-valid-range`.

Comment: I'm afraid there are too many very unclear things in your code snippet for us to provide an accurate answer. First, if `add` is an address, it should not be declared as `unsigned short`, but either as `uintptr_t` or directly as `unsigned short *` (with the initializer being `(unsigned short *)0x01`). Second, why do you have a `volatile` in your cast of `add` as address? Third, the assertion really does not make any sense from a typing point of view. You can compare `temp` with `(unsigned short *)` values, or `*temp` with `(unsigned short)` values, or `&temp` with `(unsigned short **)` values.

Comment: @Virgile: First, actually, in my code, temp is the address, add is just an unsigned short value. Sorry for confusing variable names. Second, I add "volatile" to show the invariants in source code as I think it will be a valid statement with/ without "volatile". Third, yes, you're right.  "Comparing temp with (unsigned short *) 0x01" is the answer to my question.  If you don't mind, please write it in the answer section so that I can accept it.

Comment: @ThuyNguyen Well, I can write an answer if you wish so, but the one of user3629249 below seems already pretty accurate. You can accept it instead.

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
assert &temp == (unsigned short) 0x01;
```

This is trying to compare the address of `temp` (which is on the stack) with some address (other than that location on the stack).  Naturally, the `assert()` is triggered

The correct way to access the contents of a specific address in memory is:

```
temp =  *(unsigned short *) 0x01;
```

Comment: I think you're right. But I can not accept your answer as the answer to this question. Because what I am looking for is the right way to get the add value through the temp variable.

Comment: then you should have specified that goal in the question.

Comment: @user3629249 I think your answer might be clearer if you make your second code snippet an assertion like the first one (`assert temp == *(unsigned short *)0x01;`) rather than an assignment.